# How to encode categorical data for use with Semi-supervised algorithm LabelPropagation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I am attempting to use the anneal.arff dataset with Python scikit-learn's semisupervised algorithm LabelPropagation. The anneal dataset is categorical data, so I preprocessed it so that the output class for each item of instance 
looks like [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.].  This is a numeric list that encodes the output class
as 5 possible values with 0's everywhere, and 1. in the position of the corresponding class.  This is what I would expect.

For semi-supervised learning, most of the training data must be unlabeled, so
I modified the training set so that the unlabeled data has output [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]. I previously tried just using -1, but the code emits the same error as shown below.

I train the classifier as follows, Y_train includes labeled and "unlabeled" data:

```
lp_model = LabelSpreading(gamma=0.25, max_iter=5)
lp_model.fit(X, Y_train)
```

I receive the error shown below after calling the fit method:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\semi_supervised\label_propagation.py", line 221, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 526, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 562, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (538, 5)
```

This suggests that something is wrong with the shape of my Y_train list,
but this is the correct shape.  What am I doing wrong?

Can LabelPropagation take as training data in this form, or does it only 
accept unlabeled data as a scalar -1?

--- edit ---
Here is the code that generates the error. I'm sorry about the confusion over algorithms--I want to use both LabelSpreading and LabelPropagation, and choosing one or the other doesn't fix this error.

```
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from copy import deepcopy

from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelPropagation
from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelSpreading


f = "../../Documents/UCI/anneal.arff"
dataAsRecArray, meta = arff.loadarff(f)
dataset_raw = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataAsRecArray)
dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset_raw)
class_names = [col for col in dataset.columns if 'class_' in col]
print (dataset.shape)
number_of_output_columns = len(class_names)
print (number_of_output_columns)


def run(name, model, dataset, percent):
    # Split-out validation dataset
    array = dataset.values
    X = array[:, 0:-number_of_output_columns]
    Y = array[:, -number_of_output_columns:]
    validation_size = 0.40
    seed = 7
    X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size,                                                                                random_state=seed)
    num_samples = len(Y_train)

    num_labeled_points = math.floor(percent*num_samples)

    indices = np.arange(num_samples)
    unlabeled_set = indices[num_labeled_points:]

   Y_train[unlabeled_set] = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
   lp_model = LabelSpreading(gamma=0.25, max_iter=5)
   lp_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
   """
   predicted_labels = lp_model.transduction_[unlabeled_set]

   print(predicted_labels[:10])
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #percentages = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
    percentages = [0.1]

    models = []

    models.append(('LS', LabelSpreading()))
    #models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
    #models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
    #models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
    # evaluate each model in turn
    results = []
    names = []
    for name, model in models:
        for percent in percentages:
            run(name, model, dataset, percent)
    print ("bye")
```

Comment: This is unclear. How are you generating the train and test data. You are using `y_train` with `X`. Why not `X_train`? Or `X` is your `X_train`? You talk about LabelPropagation, but code is about LabelSpreading. You need to show the complete code along with some data so that we can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Y_train has shape (538, 5) but should be 1d. LabelPropagation doesn't support multi-label or multi-output multi-class right now.
The error message could be more informative, though :-/

Comment: So then this is my problem: Y_train needs to be 538 x 1 to work with LabelPropagation.  The original data has one output class field that can take on 5 possible categorical values. So pandas get_dummies() method

Comment: binarized the field using one-hot encoding like  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.].  It might be reasonable to replace this list/array with the index of the non-zero value.
But this seems to me to defeat the purpose of one-hot encoding.
So what is the recommended approach here?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, you can leave the categorical values in y.

Comment: To clarify: does this mean I need to one-hot encode the input values, which are categorical, but not the output values?

Comment: Indeed, these are treated quite differently. Though missing labels *must* be indicated with -1.